# rename files which produced by split

Tags: linux, split, rename, nested-loops

I splitted the huge file and output is several files which start by *x* character.

I want to rename them and make a list which sorted by name like below:

part-1.gz

part-2.gz

part-3.gz  ...

I tried below CMD:

`` for (( i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )) ;do for f in `ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | grep '^x'`; do mv $f part-$i.gz ;done ; done; ``

`` for f in `ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | grep '^x'`; do for i in 1 .. 3 ; do mv -- "$f" "${part-$i}.gz" ;done ; done; ``

`` for i in 1 .. 3 ;do for f in `ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | grep '^x'`; do mv -- "$f" "${part-$i}.gz" ;done ; done; ``

`` for f in `ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | grep '^x'`; do mv -- "$f" "${f%}.gz" ;done ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip: don't do `ls -l` if you only need the file names. Even better, don't use `ls` at all, just use the shell's globbing ability. `x*` expands to all file names starting with `x`.

Here's a way to do it:

```
i=1; for f in x*; do mv $f $(printf 'part-%d.gz' $i); ((i++)); done
```

This initializes `i` to 1, and then loops over all file names starting with `x` in alphabetical order, assigning each file name in turn to the variable `f`. Inside the loop, it renames `$f` to `$(printf 'part-%d.gz' $i)`, where the `printf` command replaces `%d` with the current value of `i`. You might want something like `%02d` if you need to prefix the number with zeros. Finally, still inside the loop, it increments `i` so that the next file receives the next number.

Note that none of this is safe if the input file names contain spaces, but yours don't.